# Hide a div after the user clicks on a child menu item

Tags: javascript, menu, onclick

I'm working with a javascript menu and need help hiding the menu after the user clicks a link in the child menu. The menu works well out of the box, except when the user clicks the back button on their browser it remains stuck open.

The code that hides the child menu:

```
divref.style.visibility = "hidden";
```

I think it needs to go in this section of code:

```
this.finishOpeningChild = function(divref, ulref, maxwidth) {
    this.isChildMenuOpen = true;
    this.isChildMenuClosed = false;
    ulref.style.left = "0px";
    divref.style.width = maxwidth + "px";

}
```

How do I make the browser look for the `onClick` scenario then call: `divref.style.visibility = "hidden";` in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure in what context this is all running, but perhaps you have a statement on the page which checks to see if the menu is open, and closes it if it is, this would happens on page load ... so if the user clicks the back button and ends up on the page the below check would run ...

```
if ('hidden' != divref.style.visibility) divref.style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

Comment: Your idea works some of the time, but the problem seems to happen when I hit the back button and the page does not reload the scripts for some reason. It just displays the previous page again as it was when I left it.